# Get Constant name from value in VB6

Tags: vb6, constants

I have defined some Global Constants:

```
'Reason Codes'
 Global Const MQRC_NONE = 0
 Global Const MQRC_APPL_FIRST = 900
 Global Const MQRC_APPL_LAST = 999
```

Now I want to get the constant name from its value in VB6.

Is it possible, I know it can be done in .Net and Java. Not sure about vb6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a select statement. I do not like this solution but at least you can get things done with it.

```
    Select Case constantValue
            Case MQRC_NONE 
                 result = "MQRC_NONE"
            Case MQRC_APPL_FIRST
                 result = "MQRC_APPL_FIRST"
            Case MQRC_APPL_LAST
                 result = "MQRC_APPL_LAST"
            Case Else
                 result = "N/A"
    End Select
```

If you have control over the constant values make them range 0,1,2. Then you can just index another array of equivalent constant strings based on this constant index.

Comment: I think in vb6 this is the only way. Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: An improvement would be to use the actual constant name in the `Case` statements. No reason to hardcode the 'magic' values.

Comment: @DaveInCaz thanks, I changed the answer accordingly.